# Wierd behavior from method generating MD5 hash - returns same hash results

Tags: iphone, ios, hash, md5

I'm quite puzzled. I'm using this method in my app, and when I pass in two different strings, it can return me the same result.

But when I copy this method to another app, my results are normal - I get back two totally different results for both the strings.

```
+(NSString *) returnMD5HashOfString:(NSString*)aString 
{   
    // Create byte array of unsigned chars
    unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    // Create 16 byte MD5 hash value, store in buffer
    CC_MD5(aString, aString.length, md5Buffer);

    // Convert MD5 value in the buffer to NSString of hex values
    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) 
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x",md5Buffer[i]];

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CC_MD5 does not expect a string, it expects a char pointer.

Comment: Great. Thanks, I went to the source where I got the methods from and realized I misunderstood some parts of it. That also explains why the generated hashes are different when I hashed the same value in command line. I'm curious to know why would the method return the same 'hash' given my error codes!

Comment: Coincidence. The char pointer was pointing to memory and one would have to guess that was the same to the length of the string.  The memory was pointing to the class instance and not to the string.